# Qt: QWidget doesn't show when running the application?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwidget

My Qt application works fine and, finally yesterday, I manage to create the executable and it is ready for distribution.

Today though, I want to add more features but whenever I try to add/remove a QWidget to the mainwindow.ui on Qt-designer, the changes never displayed when running the application in either release or debug mode !. It always shows me the old version (i.e.: before the modification)

why does this happen and how to fix this ?

**UPDATE:**

I have to mention that after deploying my application, I changed the application name as follow:

1. opened Qt-creator, in .pro file, change TARGET value
2. closed QT-creator, go to source folder and rename it
3. inside the source folder, renamed the .pro file too

afterward, I realized that whenever I change anything in the Qt-Designer, these changes never take place when running the app.

Comment: Right click on the project name. Clean, Run qmake and then Rebuild the application. You can alternatively just delete the build directories and rebuild.

Comment: @nnb I did that already but nothing changed

Comment: @nnb check question update please, thanks

Comment: How are you running the application, directly from disk or from QtCreator?

Comment: @Ionut from Qt-creator

Comment: Check in Projects -> Run Settings for the build configuration you're running that the executable name and path are correct (that it uses the new name of the executable).

Comment: @Ionut : Both path and executable name are correct in Project->Run->Executable & Working directory

Comment: I tried your exact steps and it appears to work correctly (Qt Creator 3.5.1). Two more ideas come to mind: 1. delete the build folders completely from outside QtCreator (both the old one and the new one after the rename if they are different); 2. in the project folder, besides `project.pro` you should have also a `project.pro.user` file - try to look through it and see if the old target or project name appears anywhere.

Comment: @Ionut : 1- If, by build folders, you mean the debug & release folders, then I deleted them from outside the QtCreator. 2- All the names inside he `project.pro.user` are correct. Still, the application doesn't show changes when it runs in debug (or release) mode from QtCreator. I have to say the applications itself runs fine and all functionalists work as expected. But it seems like no more modifications are allowed.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas... The behavior most likely means that it either doesn't build what it should or it doesn't run what it just built, but both of these should be visible in settings or the project files. You could try something like this: close QTCreator; copy the project folder to a different location; if the build folder is somewhere inside this folder, delete it, so the new folder contains only source code and support files; delete the project.pro.user file; open QtCreator and manually open the project from the new location. It should ask you to regenerate the project settings.

Comment: @Ionut : Sadly, last attempt generates same result too .. THANK you for your help though, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Close QtCreator, remove all .pro.user files, remove all shadow build directories, remove all build files (all .o, moc_, ui_* etc.). Start QtCreator, load project as it was new project (start with blank session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly caused by mixing in-source and shadow builds. This most commonly happens, if you let Qt Creator use it's default setting (use shadow build directory), and then also build from command line in the source directly.

Qt application build generates a bunch of source files, `moc_*.cpp` (and corresponding object files) and `ui_*.h`. Now if you have these files both in shadow build directory, and in source directory, then the files in source directory are used first. So you can for example edit your GUI with designer, and have new `ui_*.h` files generated in the shadow build directory, but never used, because you have stale version in the source directory.

Solution is to remove all these files from source directory. If you accidentally committed them to version control, be sure to remove them from there also. If you are unsure what you are doing, take backups first.

One way to clean the source dir is to go there with Qt command line, then run `qmake`, then run `make clean distclean`. That should leave it quite clean. Getting rid of shadow build dirs is easier: just delete them, since they only contain generated files.

Note that you *should* be using the shadow build dirs, it has many benefits (and the only drawback really is, that if you accidentally pollute the source dir with generated files, you get the problem you have now...).

Comment: Thank you first for the thorough explanation. Thank you again for the simple explanation. Thank you one more time for solving my dilemma. `qmake`  and `make clean distclean` did the magic.

Comment: Just a follow up question: what are the benifits of the shadow build dirs ?

Comment: @Suda.nese The major general benefit is, you can have any number of different builds without their generated files getting mixed up. With in-tree *qmake* build you can only have debug+release builds for single toolchain (unless you add a lot of directory definition cruft manually). Total separation of generated and editable files brings a bunch of smaller benefits.